# NSPredicate to return only entities with connected with other entities in one to many relationships

Tags: ios, nspredicate, relationship

Simple question:

I have an entity `group` that has to_many relationship with `contact` entity.
I wish to find only the `group` entities that their contacts set has at least one `contact`.

Tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K != NULL", GroupRelationships.contact];
```

But no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do it use the count of the relationship:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contacts.@count > 0"];
```